# Install Redis using a bash script, setting configuration files

Tags: bash, 18.04, redis

I want to create a bash script, that automatically install redis:

My issues is to change lines in 2 files:

```
#Install Redis
sudo apt install redis-server
sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

1. ---

I need to find a line and changed.The supervised directive is set to no by default.

```
# Note: these supervision methods only signal "process is ready."
# They do not enable continuous liveness pings back to your supervisor.    
supervised systemd # this line to change
```

---

```
sudo systemctl reload redis.service
```

2. ---

   sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf

   Need to uncomment (remove the # if it exists):

   ```
   bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
   ```

---

It is possible also to test it ?

```
redis-cli
```

In the prompt that follows, test connectivity with the ping command:

ping

```
Output
PONG
```

or check status ?

```
sudo systemctl status redis
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but you're going about suboptimally. It's a batch process, so don't use `nano`, use text-processing tools. Instead of prefixing each command with `sudo`, wrap the whole thing in a script, and use `sudo` to execute the script.

Something like (by "Something like", I mean "I have not tried this, 
nor installed redis-server. I view this as another example of a task I've done many times, but it should work") :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]] ; then
    echo "Must be run as root" >&2
    exit 1
fi
apt update
apt install redis-server
# Just in case, ...
systemctl stop redis-server
# Change "supervised no" so "supervised systemd"? Question is unclear
# If "#bind 127.0.0.1 ::1", change to "bind 127.0.0.1 ::1"
sed -e '/^supervised no/supervised systemd/' \
    -e 's/^# *bind 127\.0\.0\.1 ::1/bind 127.0.0.1 ::1' \
    /etc/redis/redis.conf >/etc/redis/redis.conf.new
# $(date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S) == "18Aug13-125913"
mv /etc/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf.$(date +%y%b%d-%H%M%S)
mv /etc/redis/redis.conf.new /etc/redis/redis.conf
systemctl start redis-server
# give redis-server a second to wake up
sleep 1
if [[ "$( echo 'ping' | /usr/bin/redis-cli )" == "PONG" ]] ; then
    echo "ping worked"
else
    echo "ping FAILED"
fi
systemctl status redis
systemctl status redis-server
exit 0
```